# Typescript convert type Tuple of tuple to Tuple (flatten Tuple)

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have this

```
Type T = Params<[Tuple1, Tuple2]> // eg [[string], [number]]
```

How to make of it (flatten)

```
Type Flatten<T> = Params<[string, number]>
```

Answer (score 4):

We can do that by mapped types. Consider the code:

```
type T = Params<[Tuple1, Tuple2]>

// utility type
type Flatten<T extends any[]> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends any[] ? T[K][0] : T[K]
}
type Result = Flatten<T>
// evaluates into [string, number]

const a: Result = ['a', 1] // correct value of the type
```

Pay attention how `Flatten` works:

- `[K in keyof T]` - means we want to have all keys, so in tuple say elements
- `T[K] extends any[] ? T[K][0] : T[K]` - we say if the value of the element on the given key is an array then give me a type of an first element of this array (index 0), if not leave it as is, as there is nothing to be flatten

---

If your tuples consider more then one type of the element, then above solution will take the first only. So for tuple `[string, number]` it will produce the `string`. If we want to gather all possible types inside the tuple we can create more sophisticated type. Consider:

```
type Flatten<T extends any[]> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends any[] ? T[K][Exclude<keyof T[K], keyof any[]>] : T[K]
}
```

- `T[K] extends any[] ? T[K][Exclude<keyof T[K], keyof any[]>] : T[K]` means that if our element is an array then get me types of all elements, but remove types of values in array prototype.

In the result `Flatten<Params<[string, number]>>` will produce `[string | number]`. So it depends what is your goal.

---

The last proposition is, if you don't consider other types and only nested array/tuples, we can avoid conditional types. Consider last solution:

```
type Flatten<T extends E[], E extends any[] = any[]> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K][Exclude<keyof T[K], keyof any[]>]
}
```

Above type is more restrict as it works with only `[[]]` but is more concise and specific.

Comment: works great thanks, only problem if it are function params that it loses the param name like x: string now it becomes param_0: string. best would be something like [...TupleParams1, ...TupleParams2] but that doesnt work

Comment: @luky can you be more clear hear, not fully follow. What you need to pass to the function extacly?

Comment: U can use the result type like - `function f(...args: Flatten<T>) {}`

Comment: hm it is actually two Params of two functions but i will try it again because TS helper Parameters<> also capture the param names eg "x: string" etc

Comment: U can use it as two params like `function f(first: Flatten<T>[0], second: Flatten<T>[1]) {}`

Comment: check the playground, place cursor over the c() and d() in the left window https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=6&ssc=1&pln=7&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgNgQ2MCA7APAFShAHi1AEwGcoBRAbQF0AacnfNEqBVEaqAXhbeoD4uUAN4AoKFAoBpKAEtUUANYQQAewBmUTFQBcmqVQplcAYzgBXQhHRLVGzPro31PdlT5URAXxEjjK1MTALIIAFLi6gQBOcgDmAJRcAkJQ3r7+gVDGoQB0uQiRMcS6AAr5CAC2ECiRxOigkM4IfAnJ3n4BQYQ5eQVFsIjIaOgUpZEVVRA1deAQje4tKT7GIXEihCtAA

Comment: Yes see that, I mean it differently shows the name of the argument, I am not sure it can be fixed, sorry.

Comment: One more problem, the Flatten type drops partial keys, so all are required now.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgNgQ2MCA7APAFShAHi1AEwGcoBRAbQF0AacnfNEqBVEaqAXhbeoD4uUAN4AoKFAoBpKAEtUUANYQQAewBmUTFQBcmqVQplcAYzgBXQhHRLVGzPro31PdlT5URAXxEjjK1MTALIIAFLgA-LqBAE5yAOYAlFwCQlDeIgD0GVB+AUHGoQB0xQjRccS68EgE6BQACqUIALYQKNHE6KCQzgjufAm+-oE5RSVlFbCIyGi1DdHNrRDtneAQPX1JnClpANw+xiEJQA

Comment: Not so simple to solve. I get you but I think we are far away from the original question. My suggestion is to create another one. Take a look that orginal question does not say anything about function arguments at all.

Answer (score 3):

You can now define recursive types:

```
type Flatten<T> = (
    T extends [] ? [] :
    T extends [infer T0] ? [...Flatten<T0>] :
    T extends [infer T0, ...infer Ts] ? [...Flatten<T0>, ...Flatten<Ts>] : [T]
)
```

```
type T = Flatten<[[number, number, []], string, [[]], [string, [number, string]]]>
// T is [number, number, string, string, number, string]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgNgQ2MCA7APAFQHxQLxQAUAUFGVJlBAB4qoAmAzlANoC6UA-KxwFynlKNOk1YBLVADMIAJwoAGDtxYA6NfCR0s87HwFkhtNKJYTpczPIA0UNSrOyKjJazsbkabdhtvEHjJiMulC8rJhsxACUxMSgkBT4sH5aLCyoAK4AtgBGsjYZOXk8bDaMwDISAOY2qWwlrGUVqNWsBbkypeVVdWzYQA).