# Flatten nested tuple type and preserve order

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Im trying to accomplish something like this:

```js
type Type = object;
type TypeTuple = readonly Type[];

function flattenTuples<T extends readonly (Type | TypeTuple)[], R = Flatten<T>>(...tuples: T): R {
  // flatten tuple and return with correct ordering
  // example: flattenTuples(A, B, [C, D], [A]) => [A, B, C, D, A]
}
```

Where the `flattenTuples` function will flatten each tuple in the supplied parameter and the type `Flatten<T>` implementation will do the same and return a tuple eg. "`as const`" array and preserve the ordering of the parameter tuple. I only need 1 level flattening.

Example again (A, B etc are all different class constructors):

```js
const flat = flattenTuples(A, B, [C, D], [A]);
// this would make the variable flat's type:
// [A, B, C, D, A]
```

I tried the answer of a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59392640/typescript-convert-type-tuple-of-tuple-to-tuple-flatten-tuple) but his Flatten type solution did not work. With example above it produces type `[A, B, C | D, A]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE for TS4.5:**

Now that TypeScript supports [recursive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) with [tail recursion elimination](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types), `Flatten<T>` can be written directly and for arbitrarily long arrays as

```
type Flatten<T extends readonly any[], A extends readonly any[] = []> =
    T extends [infer F, ...infer R] ?
    Flatten<R, F extends readonly any[] ? [...A, ...F] : [...A, F]> :
    A

type InputTuple = [A, B, [C, D], [A, B, D], [A, B, C, D, B], A];
type FlattenedTuple = Flatten<InputTuple>;
// type FlattenedTuple = [A, B, C, D, A, B, D, A, B, C, D, B, A]
```

In fact, you can even get arbitrarily deep flattening by applying another layer of recursion:

```
type FlattenDeep<T extends readonly any[], A extends readonly any[] = []> =
    T extends [infer F, ...infer R] ?
    FlattenDeep<R, F extends readonly any[] ? [...A, ...FlattenDeep<F>] : [...A, F]> :
    A

type InputDeepTuple = [A, B, [C, D], [A, B, D], [A, B, [[C], D], [B]], A];
type FlattenedDeepTuple = FlattenDeep<InputTuple>;
// type FlattenedDeepTuple = [A, B, C, D, A, B, D, A, B, C, D, B, A]
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgNgQ2MCA7APAFShAHi1AEwGcoAnCBQge1ThCgVRAG0BdAGigEEd80S5SjToMmrNlAC8UdgD5pAWABQUNVGx4CglgEtUAMwhlYXAHQX9RkwCVJAfhXrYiZGnQ2uMPttIUqtPSMzOxQ9rIWZtzmFjCSAFwRFtGwbArxTurcKiqgkFAAkqhgAK7AmCVgcNAyLCkAQlwsAMJcACKcsg3tnXVcjVCtUG39ndxsANy54NDwSAQQhBVVNS7z7kWl5ZXVclPKAPQHUHmzrgtLO6t9UANDIzz97Vzdg8+3L2w5yvooZAYIADG0F4AG9GIliMAyPoAOZQAC+Kl+xgBwNuUHBACNIdC4Yjkag-mjoM1MVBAbiYah4UifkTUUDoG1yYQqfi6UA)

---

**answer for TS4.0**

TS4.0 will introduce [variadic tuple types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39094) in which concatenation of a fixed number of tuples `A`, `B`, `C`, is as simple as using `[...A, ...B, ...C]`.  That means `Flatten<T>` can be implemented *something* like this:

```
type ConcatX<T extends readonly (readonly any[])[]> = [
    ...T[0], ...T[1], ...T[2], ...T[3], ...T[4],
    ...T[5], ...T[6], ...T[7], ...T[8], ...T[9],
    ...T[10], ...T[11], ...T[12], ...T[13], ...T[14],
    ...T[15], ...T[16], ...T[17], ...T[18], ...T[19]
];
type Flatten<T extends readonly any[]> =
    ConcatX<[...{ [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends any[] ? T[K] : [T[K]] }, ...[][]]>

type InputTuple = [A, B, [C, D], [A, B, D], [A, B, C, D, B], A];
type FlattenedTuple = Flatten<InputTuple>;
// type FlattenedTuple = [A, B, C, D, A, B, D, A, B, C, D, B, A]
```

It still doesn't work for arbitrarily long tuples (or for edge cases such as open-ended tuples), but it's much less crazy than it was before.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=4.0.0-pr-39094-7#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwMYENgA0A8AVKEAewECAJgM5QBOEKJiANiFABTW0NMoIgDaAugEp+APigBeKDwCwAKCjyoAOmXYeABj4AaJSp4BGLTsWqATIeXGeAZnO6ALFtkKjqgKy3LANg+qA7D54ADgCATkc5BQtVPQ1tKP0DON09MyTLPRs06IdNJ0jk9yz9byK9f1Lg0rCoWT4AbllQSCgAMXo0IgQcPEJicioaOgRGKC5ePlExPPl4ZDQsHgsAb0kAaSgASwQoAGsIEDgAMyhsPgAuE55Vvh7O-rH+KAB+S+uoC55Va5uAXzT+fgTWTAmSNcDQACSCDAAFdgNgYWB6NAJDwAILaABC2h4MG0ABFDOisQSiRioNjYASsYY0fUwc02h1iBASAikSjWu1gJ1MFDYfDEcjhA0ZAB6MVQJrQJk8llsoWc4kU7R4qD47TkykaqBa1XUlW6vggrZESiHFBIaBoqArFAXMjAShbADmUB+slNEHNlugmNtUAARg6na73Z6EGaLVbYAGkCHnQg3R6ZF6fTH8QGSAmwymgA)

---

**PRE-TS4.0 answer:**

The TypeScript type system isn't really geared toward letting you do this.  The most obvious implementation of something like `Flatten` would be a recursive conditional type; this is [not currently supported (see microsoft/TypeScript#26980)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26980).  You can do it, but there's no guarantee that it will keep working in future versions of TypeScript.  And even if you get a working version, it's really easy to make it so that it blows out the TypeScript compiler, causing exceptionally long compile times and even compiler hangs and crashes.  The first version of `Flatten` that I wrote as a test had this problem, taking forever to work on even an output tuple of length 7, and occasionally reporting type instantiation depth errors.

I think the canonical GitHub issue for this feature might be [microsoft/TypeScript#5453](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453), a proposal to support [variadic (arbitrary length)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/variadic) [kinds (basically "types of types")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kind_(type_theory)).  Right now the only officially-supported way to manipulate tuples in a variadic way is to prepend a fixed number of types onto the beginning, by using [tuples in rest/spread positions](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions).

---

So the "official" answer is something like "you can't or shouldn't do this", but that doesn't stop people from doing it.  There's even a library called [`ts-toolbelt`](https://pirix-gh.github.io/ts-toolbelt/index.html) which does all kinds of fun recursive things under the covers to get more arbitrary tuple manipulation.  I think the author of this library has really tried to make sure that the compiler performance doesn't suffer, so if I were going to really use anything, I'd probably use that library rather than write it myself.  One of the tools on that belt is called [`Flatten<L>`](https://pirix-gh.github.io/ts-toolbelt/modules/_list_flatten_.html) which seems to do what you want.  But even this library is still [not officially supported](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26980#issuecomment-566152178).

---

Still I couldn't resist writing my own version of `Flatten`, to give you some idea of how hairy it is.  It seems to perform well enough.  I've limited it to concatenating only up to about 7 tuples, and the total length of the flattened output can't exceed about 30 elements.  It uses both iterative and recursive conditional types, the latter of which is unsupported.  A particularly clever person might come up with a way to do it completely iteratively, but I am either not that person or it would take me too long to become that person.  Okay, enough preamble, here it is:

```
/* 
codegen
var N = 30;
var range = n => (new Array(n)).fill(0).map((_,i)=>i);
var s = [];
s.push("type Add = ["+range(N).map(i => "["+range(N-i).map(j => i+j+"").join(",")+"]").join(",")+"];")
s.push("type Sub = ["+range(N).map(i => "["+range(i+1).map(j => i-j+"").join(",")+"]").join(",")+"];")
s.push("type Tup = ["+range(N).map(i => "["+range(i).map(_=>"0").join(",")+"]").join(",")+"];")
console.log(s.join("\n"))
*/
type Add = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [26, 27, 28, 29], [27, 28, 29], [28, 29], [29]];
type Sub = [[0], [1, 0], [2, 1, 0], [3, 2, 1, 0], [4, 3, 2, 1, 0], [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0], [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0], [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0], [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0], [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0], [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0], [11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0], [12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0], [13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0], [14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0], [15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0], [16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0], [17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0], [18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0], [19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0], [20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0], [21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0], [22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0], [23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0], [24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0], [25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0], [26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0], [27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0], [28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0], [29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]];
type Tup = [[], [0], [0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]];

type Arr = readonly any[];

type Tail<T extends Arr> =
    ((...x: T) => void) extends ((h: infer A, ...t: infer R) => void) ? R : never
type Concat<T extends Arr, U extends Arr> = Tup[Add[T["length"]][U["length"]]] extends infer A ? {
    [I in keyof A]: I extends keyof T ? T[I] : U[Sub[Extract<I, keyof Sub>][T["length"]]]
} : never

// in TS4.0, Tail and Concat can be simplified to 
// type Tail<T extends Arr> = T extends [infer A, ...infer R] ? R : never;
// type Concat<T extends Arr, U extends Arr> = [...T, ...U];

type Tuplize<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends any[] ? T[K] : [T[K]] }

type Flatten<T extends readonly any[], N extends number = 7> =
    N extends 0 ? [] :
    Tuplize<T> extends infer U ? U extends Arr ?
    { 0: [], 1: Concat<U[0], Extract<Flatten<Tail<U>, Extract<Sub[N][1], number>>, Arr>> }[
    U extends [] ? 0 : 1] : never : never;
```

The first three lines are generated by a small JS script, to produce a bunch of fixed tuples representing the operations of adding and subtracting numbers, and to also get a "blank" tuple of a given length.  So `Add[3][4]` should be `7`, `Sub[7][3]` should be `4`, and `Tup[3]` should be `[0,0,0]`.

From there I define `Tail<T>`, which takes a tuple like `[1,2,3,4]` and strips off the first element to produce `[2,3,4]`, and `Concat<T, U>` which takes two tuples and concatenates them (like `Concat<[1,2],[3,4]>` should be `[1,2,3,4]`).  The definition of `Concat` here is purely iterative so it's not illegal yet.

Then I make `Tuplize<T>`, which just makes sure each element of the tuple `T` is itself an array.  So your `[A, B, [C, D], [A]]` will become `[[A],[B],[C,D],[A]]`.  This removes the weird edge conditions you get when flattening.

Finally I write the illegal and recursive `Flatten<T>`.  I tried to put some recursion limiting in there; it will only work for lengths up to 7 or so.  If you try to increase that just by changing `7` to `25` you're liable to get errors from the compiler.  Anyway, the basic approach here is to do a sort of `reduce()` operation on `Tuplize<T>`: just `Concat` the first element of `Tuplize<T>` on to the `Flatten`-ed version of the `Tail` of `Tuplized<T>`.

Let's see an example:

```
type InputTuple = [A, B, [C, D], [A, B, D], [A, B, C, D, B], A];
type FlattenedTuple = Flatten<InputTuple>;
// type FlattenedTuple = [A, B, C, D, A, B, D, A, B, C, D, B, A]
```

Looks good.

There are all sorts of caveats here; it only flattens one level deep (which is what you asked for).  It probably doesn't distribute over unions.  It might not act the way you want with `readonly` or optional tuples or arrays.  It definitely won't act properly with tuples that are too long or of arbitrary length.  It might not act properly if the moon is full or if Jupiter aligns with Mars, etc.

The point of the above code is *not* for you to drop it into your production system.  Please don't do that.  It's just to have some fun with the type system and show that this is an open issue.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN7LgLmQRmQF8BYAKFElkRQCFNkAjPQ0i8aeJZAYQYRbFylTjWQARBgBNBbcgHoAVMnIIA9lIgBzCCHIA3OFGQA5ZAF5kAZgAMAbgNHkUOCB0XkICwD5kAChAIAHc0KBcATwCASiiAOhhgABtEvxs4gFs4AAc-PwB9ABpgKPNvYocyQ2MAZw8AbQBdCurYrIBXaoALPwAiMHCslFQpKXqegGoXNwg-Ewzsv2AfZB66iamdWYBaYtjMnIArZeBxg-GenriDtVBegsvzhsvY69ue+6jHu0vyFvau3r9QbIADKbUYY0mrk2cz2CyWpRWayh00W43w80Oxy2ZwuVxuIDuDx6T3xbw+Xx+ZD+HW6fQGKAAKm0spCNjNYftFstVutoTNdly8qUejZnq9Ce9iaSXgSiZ8Sd8oqo1CBqmpEhBYok1Fo-C0Jb0ADogS7KsiKeTkIFDEb1Oo2AoEJ0AJidVidABYnQBWJ0ANidAHYnQAOJ0ATid+EdBHw0bdBA9BG9BD9BEDBBDBHDBCjyBdsZd8YLiZdyZdqZd6ZdmZd2ZduZdEYaTrqJcTydT6cz2dz+Zj0ZL+ET+GT+FT+HT+Ez+Gz+Fz+HzhddHbLFarNbrDabLbbna9voDwbDkejsfww9H48n09n88Xy6La9dG9dW9dO9de+QdS7R+QXtT2QAcLyvaMb2jO9owfaMn1XV111dTdXW3V1d1bX9u2PZA+zPAgwITCDo1vaN72jR9XWfRDX2Q99UM-dDv0wuoexPZB+3PIciKTEioLImCKLgqiENLWiCxQgs0ILDC2yAjj8MHOMeLHPi0wErMhLzESCxfAs3wLD8Cy-AsfzqPCQK45SCGvNSpw0uctKXHTixo-S6MMhjjKY0yWM4gjuJs4iU34jNBJzYSC2osT3Ik+ipMYmTmLbUDApHYKJ1CmdwoXSKV10tzyw86svPrHzmxYpTLxUyD1LCzSIu0qLRJdJC4s8hLvKS3y22qoLeJCursoa3Kmvy1yYqK9qSs6sruoq3rbMG+z6scxrnOagrJoMmba0Sxtkt-VTlugkbKM2ibWvEyt4r2rqDp6o7SNW2Cxuiq7Ypujq7rmh6FqO061tGjbxr0qavt26S-rM4agfO0HCp2ozftko7XpB962oh5GTP+9t4cx67JJ+3GYfgraPvB4modRuoEe24qcfKszLqx6n9tpymkdK0mWKp26acOun2fuzmmfmlnBceunef3TmWyaa0GVBcF7RsSqnXV-do01liKx15Ataw91XQNo3WMPaxTedQ2WMzdNU31m3zeze3LadktzdzV2AMd63PZY-NvZwh2TYLM3KtjIP2Ld5A-fD53KuHKPgJ95BQ6thOA8WtKU4U3CQ-d-3dd68dR2T-Dg8A32w9HEunoy8urOjgvq-Tous-r9tp0nMvc8rmOa8zuvbd62ce8b-vLPztOM49rugfHuy++spSW9njuR-N4H5yX5aV76tfU8LuPa4j3qB0XXest7lSK+nqvY-jre+YvS+cr3zKBvS1e88fof56j1-JdN+Tlr5DVvv1Q+f9B7t1PsPc+wCywdlAetcBK0v7HR-tAgercn5n0TvuCsyCdIbR3g5Ce38m4BQfrAuexcgHC2uiQzaZCr4UOXnfZux8270M7ow3aVZiEtVQeQ1alCsHUKPjPE+z9EF0zrDWIRhUUGRTEbDCRB977r1kQQ7OwCGyKOKsIimoj2HiM4VA7RPD8EIMIcApshjbrKMmqopq6jP6QOwdYmRvDN7yObOVJx30XGUzcWwj+N9J6-1wRveBgD1aKzIDaZAzJWSWDqI0Ns5tYw5M1l3XJ+TGGFMNkUvJpSKklPKVUspBTamVPqdUxpzTiktJqQ01pHT2ndLqV0tpbSWI9L6cMqpgz+kjPGU0iZ0yhlTNmZMgZ2SFkzOWXM1Z6yuljJWds+Zmylk7I2bs3JWyjmHMOScs5ByrlrOuZco5FzbmPNOZUh5zy3l3LKa8j5Tzzn7PeT8gFoy-nfP+aCxpXzAUgruQ0JJStgSoDCB4KAEA4BSFVIkcI2AQDhEaBUOFTI4BJAADyMmQBAAAHpAEAUhagIqgL4cw5BkDMv8H4WI7LyV4EZFEZY+gbhSB5RSqlNLWWdDwKAGA0A0BOnZbEMA4qQCSuMAAJR5YiPlwABXIAAPzIGVcgPAgR9DQHIPi3gqoEBwDACSsllLdAirpU6AAqra4VtKwgMtSSyOowwpB1EZGsTUbgwCdBJA0OoTrA26C0CGsNDRXX2tqBKqV6BdUYCZSyuoABJZAoBkAAGsIDhDUDANADQ8A5qFYmgtRaS2pJ1ak7N8a8CRrBIwOoABRSlLgEDWqzU6QtxbS1tu8OGgNPQg0xtDTCho5AiAGs8BAY1UBTXJOVmkxIwAABeEASWeqwHUAA0rmrwg662MnLY2w98aq3UtqK4HF8bdUBuvQu-1R6YVCDIGagAYokK1VKbW3pFci1F6LMUPqyaYBNd7PBtHSIwKVlggwMozcyswwHag2AbY0A1aGvVZE3TuvdMGRXJuMC63VLrMOhGMNq-DWAbB4Cg-gPAPALVWqJZGo2XawA9utX+gDugSWEsSFx7wTpeP8aJW2uoJhw34EwiAeDiH6USdo94XwRA6j4eo3a2DuHdXYZYM2xdy6F1GugHi79a7gRZpAO0MAG6UAZNQE6WgbYeBOnECxNzyAPMSF8+5p0XmJDucwqgJJKTBNgCpRAKQzmPAxcA-ZxzznvAVHkPIZA0X-2xd0PFxLrngu8G806PzAXxDlZK6Fqr-nyuzrIEAA)

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer & link to the github issue! Exactly what I needed, too bad there aint a less hacky way to do it.

Comment: [Looks like variadic types are slated for TS 4.0](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453#issuecomment-644984977) which may help this be cleaner as you mentioned

Comment: Went ahead and made an answer for those like me that are wondering what your awesome solution would look like in a world of variadic kinds and official support for recursive conditional types.

Comment: FYI, this solution breaks with boolean.  It ends up distributing.  The fix is to put brackets around the types to prevent the distribution.

`type FlattenDeep<T, A extends readonly any[] = []> = [T] extends [[infer F, ...infer R]]
  ? FlattenDeep<R, [F] extends [readonly any[]] ? [...A, ...FlattenDeep<F>] : [...A, F]>
  : A;`

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript has out [a proposal for variadic kinds](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453) our thats currently [slated for 4.0](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453#issuecomment-644984977) that would make jcalz@'s solution even more awesome:

```
type Tuple = readonly any[]
type Tail<T extends Tuple> = T extends [any, ...infer U] ? U : []
type Concat<T extends Tuple, U extends Tuple> = [...T, ...U];
type Tuplize<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends unknown[] ? T[K] : [T[K]] }

type Flatten<T extends Tuple> =
  Tuplize<T> extends infer U ?
    U extends Tuple ?
      { 0: [], 1: Concat<U[0], Flatten<Tail<U>>>}[U extends [] ? 0 : 1]
      : never
    : never;
```

This though is based on an experimental proposal and does not have recursion control like jcalz@'s answer, and, for obvious reasons, **should not be used in production** until [recursive conditional typees are actually officially supported](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26980) and until 4.0 is actually released and the syntax for variadic kinds is finalized.

It's fun to dream though, right?

---

[Playground Link](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?useDefineForClassFields=true&noUnusedLocals=true&noUnusedParameters=true&ts=4.0.0-pr-39094-7#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgrmANtAvFAThAhgEwPYB2iIUWBIA2gLoCwAUKJLFgJaIA8MUEAHsBARwBnWAmQA+KGi69+gkRTIgANFAB0GlgQBmEdFACqVKAH5DUAFxRq9RtADChAMZZgnbnwHDRSCKoMect7wvpJoFBpqMKqRRgDctuDQIYgsAF4QnGFQAN7WANJQWlAA1hAgeNqwVFYwFPnGsl4icAQlBHgA7gTUprD1xlYUdQ3GAL70iUwAYoiucu5N8j4SUvRQK+mZMJJL3lq6+gEm6xvmeyIp0Cd0Z2d5AAxDVKoAjFaOBC5uBhQPL1BZvMBJxWBwDOJIWMKAELtZjGYHpYoK9aLc7siCBAAG56U4bKxY3HoBJ0KbJCBCYBXGB4IHAORSawAcn4VOZqgorMpwAATByoNyqQBmZkAoXAAAsAq5bOAAFYxWi7LAefS5BAcFcmeqQTAeTS6XMGQJxPQgA)